# Filter database values

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table like below

```
  |-----|-----|--------|
  | id  | num | amount |
  |-----|-----|--------|
  | 101 | a   |     10 |      
  | 102 | a   |      6 |   
  | 102 | a   |      3 |
  | 101 | b   |      5 |  
  | 101 | a   |     10 |
  | 101 | b   |      5 |         
  |-----|-----|--------|
```

What i want to display is

```
  |---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
  |        id           |     num          |        amount       |
  |---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
  |       101           |       a,b        |          5          |        
  |---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

I.e if two different values in num table have the same id then their amount is added and divided by 3 and others are discarded . How can i achieve this using mysql??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: only two values or more than that is also possible ?

Comment: Hint - group by having.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya there are lot more values this is just demo

Comment: @BishalChhetri check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51998997/2469308

Comment: @Jerodev I am not an expert I am just beginner and want to learn how this kinda stuff can be handled.

Comment: Why num 'a'? Why not 'b'??

Comment: @Strawberry I  only need to display those data where two different num have same id and their sum is divided following by division

Comment: Why does 'a' appear in the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this query will do what you want. It checks for id values that have more than one distinct value of `num` associated with them, and displays the `SUM` of their amounts divided by 3. I've put a `GROUP_CONCAT` on `num` so that the output contains a list of the distinct `num` values.

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT num) AS nums, SUM(amount) / 3 AS amount
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT num) > 1
```

Output:

```
id      nums    amount
101     a,b     5
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f90c3c/13)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thankyou so much Nick.

Comment: I have less then 15 reputations no it wont show sorry :)

Comment: You can accept an answer with no reputation at all. In fact, you gain reputation by accepting answers. You just can't vote up or down. It's the little tick **below** the arrows.

Comment: Done Thankyou :)

Comment: if multiple data is matched only one data is processed and calculated how can i achieve this ??

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean? Can you update the question with some sample data which shows what you want?

Comment: I see you posted a new question. I will take a look.

Comment: Your query also calculate second value that satisfies the condition. What i want is it will only calculate one value and leaves next one

Comment: your query gives the amount 10 which is calculated twice I want 5

Comment: Since you've posted a new question, don't keep editing this one. I'll take a look at that.